# Batch line to exclude running spools

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I currently have a batch to run a command that will send some spool files directly to my default printer, however I do not want it to send .exe or .txt files to the printer.  What do I need to add to the line to exclude those file types?  I am very new to this so any help is greatly appreciated.

> for /f %%f in ('dir /b c:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS) do spool
>   %%f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the built-in *associative arrays* of the batch language:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "startfolder=c:\Windows\System32\spool\PRINTERS"
FOR %%a IN (
    .exe
    .txt
    .xls
    .doc
    .mp3
    .avi
    ) DO (
    SET "$%%a=1"
)
FOR /r "%startfolder%" %%a IN (*) DO IF NOT DEFINED $%%~xa spool "%%~fa"
```